# Xcode 6: How to solve Precompile prefix Header error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, llvm

I just moved an app i've been working on from Xcode 5, onto another computer running Xcode 6, (working fine on Xcode 5)

I now get the following error 
[image: image of error]

I assume this was an issue with a missing .pch file, when I look into this dir i found the file but its called TMU-Prefix.pch instead of TMU_4.0-Prefix.pch

I figured my prefix header must be set incorrectly so I went in to build settings to change that and to my surprise my build settings is looking for the right file 
[image: Build Settings]

This file which does indeed exist in my directory . . .

I'm clueless as to this error
upon search I came upon [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840720/xcode-6-pch-file-not-found/26126065#comment45461599_26126065) where Xcode 6 requires creating a separate .pch file i did and yet no success

As always, Any help is much appreciated

Comment: do u try Clear build folder after move the project?

Comment: yes I did :( - no success

Comment: Did you find the problem/fix? Were any of the answers correct? Can you accept or vote up or comment it to let us know if/how you fixed this?

Answer (score 0):

When you see compiler errors looking for files that exist you should straight away realise that there is a naming issue conflict somewhere in the build settings of one of your targets, this was simply the case for me : mind boggling - but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891469/app-file-not-found-in-derived-data) paved the way towards the answer

Answer (score 0):

you need to check you project name (e.g Demo) and project test name (e.g DemoTests.m ) must be same. if both name are not same then rename same as to Demo

Comment: FYI: double click the value to see if that's the actual value or the resulting value after substitution (expansion?); for example the value may actually be "${PROJECT}/${TARGET}-Prefix.pch" which may be right for the main target but wrong (not exist) for a secondary target. It might should be "${PROJECT}/${PROJECT}-Prefix.pch" or just hard coded to what you expect ("TMU_4.0/TMU-Prefix.pch").

Answer (score 0):

check both the project file build settings and target file build settings.If in any of the file its is incorrectly specified you will get error.

Comment: FYI: target settings override project settings. If all targets share the same .pch file then only define it in the project settings; If you have per-target .pch files then define them in the target settings.