# App not running: Compile error : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I've seen people ask this question before, but I have tried some of the answers and can't seem to fix the problem.

I changed the name of my app and it was working fine until I restarted Xcode now I am getting the error:

[image]

Its coming from the tests target...

If anyone can add any input would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280543/xcode-file-not-found-while-trying-to-run-app) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891469/app-file-not-found-in-derived-data) question.

Comment: Renaming is not that easy. You need to change a couple of make settings as well. The easiest (until you learn what to change) is to once again rename your project, create a new with the target name and copy/move all source to the new one.

Comment: Thanks @Glorfindel I just had to rename some files thanks!