# Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

When I run `react-native run-ios` the build succeeds but I get the error below. I've checked all over the place but nothing seems to be working. Using `sudo` in front of the command does not help either. I am using Xcode 7.3, react-native-cli: 0.2.0, react-native: 0.24.1, node v5.11.0.

```
=== BUILD TARGET mobileTests OF PROJECT mobile WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mobile.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
/Users/astiefel/workspace/bosspayments/mobile/node_modules/promise/lib/done.js:10
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mobile.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:470:13)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:490:13)
    at _runIOS (runIOS.js:91:34)
    at runIOS.js:24:5
    at tryCallTwo (/Users/astiefel/workspace/bosspayments/mobile/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
    at doResolve (/Users/astiefel/workspace/bosspayments/mobile/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)
    at new Promise (/Users/astiefel/workspace/bosspayments/mobile/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:66:3)
    at Array.runIOS (runIOS.js:23:10)
    at Object.run (/Users/astiefel/workspace/bosspayments/mobile/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js:86:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:88:7)
```

Comment: And does the bundle identifier exist in the file?  I assume not, so the question is "why isn't it being written to the file".

Comment: For me it's due react-native compatibility issue with Xcode9.4. I resolved using the following steps. "rm -rf node_modules" then "react-native upgrade" then "npm install" then "react-native run-ios"

Comment: Raja..are you sure it's possible to run react-native upgrade after you've removed the node_modules folder?  I tried and it said upgrade wasn't recognized

Comment: Just close your terminal, open it again and run the app it worked for me.

Comment: What an absolute nightmare... perhaps if there are 36 different answers to this question, spanning form 2016 to 2019, something should be done to address the underlying issue?

Comment: I've had the same issue here, I this answer helped me to figure out the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26333208/4178612. I don't know why the 'product name' has changed to another name. I just changed to the original name back, and my build worked back.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My problem was actually that my build was in Release mode instead of Debug mode. As a result, the identifier was pointing to something that was not in existence. I changed the build type and it ended up working.

Comment: But what if you want to run your project in Release mode?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7308#issuecomment-245197071 or https://medium.com/@alberto.schiabel/react-native-on-xcode-beta-8-0-how-to-fix-initial-build-error-f0225c649850#.yh77u8tt5

Comment: @astiefel I think this is what's happening to me as well. How do you change the build type by the way?

Comment: @JohnnyQ Go to `Product` -> `Scheme` -> `Edit Scheme` and then select Debug under Build Configuration

Answer (score 117):

Open Project in Xcode

If Xcode > 9
run command `react-native upgrade` (this overwrites all your iOS configurations, ***use with caution***!)

then

1.Go to File -> Project settings

2.Click the Advanced button

3.Select "Custom" and select "Relative to Workspace" in the pull down

4.Change "Build/Products" to "build/Build/Products" and "Build/Intermediates" to "build/Build/Intermediates"

[image: Add package]

5.click done, done

Comment: This worked for me on xcode 8.2, fixed my problem thanks!

Comment: @SurajShingade I have Xcode 9.4 on my machine and can't find the "Project Settings" option within "Files". I only see "Workspace Settings...". Do you know where to access Project Settings? - https://imgur.com/a/SqAemnL - holding down the option key with File menu open doesn't show it either

Comment: @PatNeedham "Project Settings" was renamed to "Workspace Settings"

Comment: Can you please explain a little why this solution works ?

Comment: This is still the way to fix it as of xCode 10

Comment: It worked but why do I have to do this now for every single new Project I'm creating? Do you have an idea?

Comment: If you dont want to have to do this for every new project in xcode you can go into Xcode->Preferences->(Locations Tab)->click Advanced then make the same change there.

Comment: I saw that path was wrong in the output, but didn't know where I can fix that, thanks a lot for this comment, works even for the latest Xcode :)

Comment: I can't find this option of "project settings" on Xcode-12.
PS: found it, it comes under "workspace setting, and it shows legacy build system is deprecated"

Comment: thanks a lot, brother, you saved my day. +1 for you.

Answer (score 70):

This is may occurs if you are missing **config.h** file,

For update **config.h** file,

1) Close your Xcode.

2) Open Terminal, go to your project's root folder and do:

```
cd node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-{X}.{X}.{X}/
```

3) Run the configure script:

```
./configure
```

4) Open Xcode and try to run your app.

> {X}: version number glog

Comment: I installed react-native from scratch, created my first project, but couldn't get that to work. This answer fixed my problem. I wonder why this happens, since it's a fresh and new installation

Comment: This worked for me. Fresh install of react-native 0.55, Xcode version 10

Comment: ... what if there is no `configure` script, as in 0.58?

Comment: Get the error : `checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in /Users/macbookpro2018/sites/calendar/node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.5
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.`

Answer (score 36):

If you're using Xcode 10, it may be due to an incompatibility with the latest build system of Xcode. Try switching to the legacy build system.

Open Xcode 10, File > Project Settings > Build System > switch dropdown to Legacy Build System.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: rats! I've lost two workdays to this issue. What's crazy is my CLI build worked just fine until 3 days ago. No idea wtf happened. This didn't fix the problem either. Wanna see a grown my cry? TT

Comment: Perfect, but it's saying legacy mode is deprecated. Is it problem?

Answer (score 28):

Update React using `react-native upgrade` did it for me.

**Disclaimer**: this overwrites all your iOS configurations, ***use with caution***!

Comment: overwriting all iOS files will overwrite any configurations you have made to your project. lol. use at your own risk disclaimer is the least you could do.

Comment: Would be helpful if someone could explain what "all your iOS configurations" means.

Comment: @AndrewKoster it means that if you change a file in the iOS directory, it'll be overwritten. Let's say you changed at Xcode the configurations for your project, e.g: adding the descriptions to when you prompt the user for permission. All these custom changes made there would be overwritten.

Comment: Does anyone know which files `react-native upgrade` might modify? Are these files part of the project? Under version control, or ignored by default? Or are they part of the OS, outside of version control? It's all very vague.

Answer (score 21):

I faced the same problem with iOS 14 and Xcode 12.

```
Error: Command failed: ...../Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

I solved it by removing my `yarn.lock` file and `node_modules` folder. Then install everything again with `yarn install`. The logic behind it is that this will upgrade your `react-native-cli` [which fixes](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli#updating-the-cli) this error.

Comment: Removing the lock file (in my case `package-lock.json` because I'm not using yarn) helped a ton. Worked for me.

Comment: Faced the issue when running `react-native run-ios --scheme XXX`. Apparently `react-native-cli` needed to be updated to fix it. Removing `yarn.lock` did the trick!

Answer (score 11):

For `react-native@0.46.4` the following did the trick for me:

1) Check your paths, open your .xcodeproj (not .xcworkspace) file and:

- go to File > Project Settings > Advanced
- custom > Relative to workspace
- set the products path to `'build/Build/Products'`
- set the intermediates path to `'build/Build/Intermediates'`
- press done and save your changes

2) Run `rm -rf ios/build` in your project's root directory

3) Close your react packager

4) Run `react-native run-ios` again

Comment: Also works on : 

"react": "16.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.52.0",

Comment: This solved issue for me after adding dependencies via Pods to the iOS part of our RN project. Except: I made this change in the `.xcworkspace` config.

Comment: @cayleyh, this did not for me exactly but it did remove the `Splashscreen` error, so are you saying you followed Tims step except you did it inside of `xcworkspace`?

Answer (score 10):

I also came across this issue as well and I found a way to fix it

**Here is what i did:**

1) Make sure there is no white spaces in the file directory.

2) cd **project directory**

3) run command **react-native upgrade**

4) Go to native ios folder and open xcode project.

5) Go to File > Project Settings > Advanced...

6) select custom > Relative to workspace

7) products path should be 'build/Build/Products'

8) intermediates path should be 'build/Build/Intermediates'

9) now try running command in your terminal **react-native run-ios**

I hope that this solutions will help some of us facing this issue.

Comment: not worked for me still i have this error :Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Answer (score 10):

The `Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist` message just indicates your project failed to compile or link. You'll need to go back through your output in order to find a hint about the actual root cause.

If you're having problems, look at the full build output, not just the last few lines. You may want to open the project in Xcode and hit ⌘B to build it. The build errors in Xcode should help you find the root cause of the failure.

Comment: Life savior. It was another issue indeed. Had my Schema renamed and the problem was solved.

Comment: In my Xcode comiling and I can able to build. While running the react-native run-ios command it failed

Answer (score 9):

I had this happen to me when my node_modules folder got screwy after installing a new package. I killed the folder `rm -rf node_modules` and then did an `npm install` to re-install my packages and that fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

If you've received this error, then you probably do not have the correct path for your application.

> An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
>   Failed to install the requested application
>   An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
>   Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
>   Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

React Native has hardcoded it as part of their run-ios command in runIOS.js

```
build/Build/Products/${configuration}-${isDevice ? 'iphoneos' : 'iphonesimulator'}/${appName}.app
```

Unfortunately, Xcode has different build paths depending on your configuration and on whether you are using an Xcode Project or Workspace.  I believe the default path for an Xcode Project is `build/Products`.
I submitted this pull request [11899](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/11899) to give programmers more flexibility from the CLI.

Answer (score 3):

For me it was a problem with accidently setting up modules using Cocoapods & `react-native link` at the same time.

Don't mix those two for same modules!

Comment: So how to go around with this?

Comment: @Isaac nuke cache and install with either cocoapods / react-native link, depending on how is your project set up

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by deleting `/build/` and running `react-native run-ios` again

Comment: @EranOr do you see `Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.` in your console? 

Try the following xcode settings `file => project settings, build system: legacy, derived data: project-relative, DerivedData in the input => advanced, custom, relative to workspace, build/Build/ in the first 2 inputs`

Answer (score 3):

I'v tried all of these solutions but the one that has worked for me is:

1. run `react-native upgrade`
2. open xcode
3. run the application in xCode
4. works fine!

Comment: thanks Eli, i have solved this issue by simply running "react-native upgrade"

Comment: For those who work in enterprise environments, I would urge caution using this solution. Upgrading the react-native core needs to be planned because it could negatively impact the work of others. Ask first.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked that you declared a bundle identifier?  You can do this by Clicking on your project file in xcode and then selecting the general tab and it is listed under the first text box under "Identity".  Another way to check is to check in your info.plist file in the ios folder of your project.  This is how it shows in my info.plist.  My actual bundle identifier for my project is in xcode.

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can follow below steps to resolve this error:

**Step 1**

```
Open terminal
```

**Step 2**

```
cd node_modules/react-native/third-party
```

**Step 3**

```
ls

Copy or identify glog-{version}
```

**Step 4**

```
cd ../../../
```

**Step 5**

```
cd node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-{version}
```

**Step 6**

```
./configure
```

*I hope this will work !!!*

Answer (score 1):

I updated Xcode to v8 and the error was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

the 0.44 is ok to run，but 0.45 can not，maybe is the version problem
i solved this by the following command：
rninit init TaxiApp --source react-native@0.44.0;

Answer (score 1):

I found how to solve the issue: do NOT use space in your project path!

Answer (score 1):

My terminal pops out the same message due to deleting some simulators I don't use in Xcode.

If you run `react-native run-ios` with no specific parameters, react-native will run the default simulator which is iPhone 6 with iOS 10.3.1 in my case and I deleted this simulator by chance.

Here comes my error messages:

```
xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
        { id:F3A7BF54-B827-4517-A30D-8B3241C8EBF8 }

Available destinations for the "albums" scheme:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:CD64F26B-045A-4E27-B05A-5255924095FB, OS:10.3.1, name:iPad Pro (9.7 inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:8FC41950-9E60-4264-B8B6-20E62FAB3BD0, OS:10.3.1, name:iPad Pro (10.5-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:991C8B5F-49E2-4BB7-BBB6-2F5D1776F8D2, OS:10.3.1, name:iPad Pro (12.9 inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B9A80D04-E43F-43E3-9CA5-21137F7C673D, OS:10.3.1, name:iPhone 7 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:58F6514E-185B-4B12-9336-B8A1D4E901F8, OS:10.3.1, name:iPhone 7 Plus }
```

.
.
.

```
Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

In order to get rid of these, open up your Xcode and check for available simulators (as same as terminal listed) and run `react-native run-ios --simulator="your device name"`

For my case, I run `react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 7"`, the problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of months trying all the answers, I finally update my OS to Sierra, Update XCode to the latest version and with that all the errors disappear. Hope this could help some folks out there!

Answer (score 1):

Adding, it works for me, when nothing above fixes:

1. Install react-native-git-upgrade and update your project. `npm i -g react-native-git-upgrade && react-native-git-upgrade`
2. Open Xcode -> File -> Project settings -> Advanced.
3. Select "*Custom*", then select "*Relative to Workspace*" and then click done, done.
4. Update your CLI. `npm i -g react-native-cli`
5. Update your Nodejs 8 and NPM. `nvm install --lts` and `nvm install-latest-npm`
6. Remove ios/build and node_modules (in your project root path)
7. Proceed again with `npm install` and `react-native run-ios`, and give me a hug :-)

It finally works here.

- Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.4
- Xcode 9.3
- NPM 5.8.0
- Node 8.11.1
- RN 0.55.2

Answer (score 1):

Using this version is work for me with xcode 10.1

```
"react": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728",
"react-native": "0.57.4"
```

Answer (score 1):

All these solution suggests have not worked for me. I have just create a rn 0.58.5 project. And compared with my project. I saw there is no `JavaScriptCore.framework` under the `Build Phasess` > `Link Binary With Libraries`. After drag and drop JavaScriptCore react-native run-ios build succeeded.

`JavaScriptCore.framework` location: `‎⁨Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨Applications⁩ ▸ ⁨Xcode⁩ ▸ ⁨Contents⁩ ▸ ⁨Developer⁩ ▸ ⁨Platforms⁩ ▸ ⁨iPhoneOS.platform⁩ ▸ ⁨Developer⁩ ▸ ⁨SDKs⁩ ▸ ⁨iPhoneOS.sdk⁩ ▸ ⁨System⁩ ▸ ⁨Library⁩ ▸ ⁨Frameworks⁩`

[image: JavaScriptCore.framework]

Answer (score 1):

For me It was ios dependencies managed by cocoapods.

Had to do this:

```
$ cd ToProject/ios

$ pod install

$ react-native run-ios
```

This worked for me

https://shift.infinite.red/beginner-s-guide-to-using-cocoapods-with-react-native-46cb4d372995

PS: Was trying to figure out work done by somebody else

Comment: running pod install said : [!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.

Comment: @MohammadMirzaeyan assumption was you have done `pod init` and you have valid Podfile. Please do not downvote If you have don't have enough knowledge to counter your claims. Since It was somebody else's project as I mentioned I already had the PodFile. I have removed pod setup completely for folks like you.

Answer (score 1):

The error message similar to `The domain/default pair of (../ios/Runner/Info, CFBundleIdentifier) does not exist`

Means Xcode think you `plist` have `invalid format content`.

You need to past out the content of `Info.plist` file to find out what's wrong with that file.

One possible problem is that this `<key>`s and `<values>`s (`<array>`s, `<string>`s, or `<bool>`s ) are not paired correct. For example:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>         //<------ here is the key
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Tagueo necesita usar la camara</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>Tagueo necesita usar el microfono</string>
<array>                                            //<------ here is the value
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>   //<------ please compare this key
<array>                                            //<------ please compare this value
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

You only need to move the `key` and `value` togather

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>        //<------ here is the key
<array>                                            //<------ follow with the value
   <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
   <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
   <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old issue, but if any questions here haven't solved your problem. I solved mine after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26333208/4178612) about another question. Let me explain:

I just had the same issue, and in my case, the `Info.plist` wasn't possible to be found, that's why my **Product Name** in **Build Settings** was wrong. *I don't know why the name has changed sometime before.*

```sh
error Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier /Users/joaolavoier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WalletApp-dkxuxrpnrdamwmchtgsxasmjabmt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WalletApp.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier /Users/joaolavoier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WalletApp-dkxuxrpnrdamwmchtgsxasmjabmt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WalletApp.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:634:15)
    at runOnSimulator (/Users/joaolavoier/Workspace/wallet-app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/index.js:191:45)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/joaolavoier/Workspace/wallet-app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

As you can see, it is looking for the **Info.plist** in `/Users/joaolavoier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WalletApp-dkxuxrpnrdamwmchtgsxasmjabmt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WalletApp.app/Info.plist`

But the **WalletApp.app** folder didn't exist.

Step to fix this:

- 1. Go to **Target > WalletApp > Build Settings tab**
- 2. Scroll to **Packaging > Product Name**
- 3. Changed the Product Name to **WalletApp**.
- 4. Removed the build folder `rm -rf /Users/joaolavoier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WalletApp-dkxuxrpnrdamwmchtgsxasmjabmt`
- 5. Clean **Product > Clean Build Folder**
- 6. Build **Product > Build**
- 7. At last in the root of your project `yarn start` and `yarn ios`.

I hope, it can help someone.

Comment: this seemed to be the issue with me too.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me Click on the RCTWebSocket project in your navigator and remove the flags under build settings > custom compiler flags
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
Follow steps https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html (Building Projects with Native Code).

Before running   **react-native run-ios** command, download boost node module from https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.63.0/ and replace node_modules/react-native/third-party/boost_1_63_0

Now run   **react-native run-ios**    command

Answer (score 0):

For me it's due react-native compatibility issue with Xcode9.4. 
I resolved using the following steps. 
on my project /ROOT

1. **rm -rf node_modules**
2. **react-native upgrade**
3. **npm install**
4. **react-native run-ios**

SOLVES the issue, this thread helped me to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I pull project from git and it also includes the ios folder.

First i remove ios folder `rm -rf ios`
then, `react-native upgrade`

Comment: This method is not secure cause it can remove a lot of particular project setups.

Comment: Total wrong, all native code written for ios will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

The basic reason is deploying port is not free.
Either you restart the device and get all ports free else run `$ lsof -i :8081` and find the process which occupied port 8081.
Kill the process which is using port 8081 by running `$ kill -9 {process_which_is_running_under_8081}`

Answer (score 0):

First run your project from Xcode then try to run from command line. That was the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am on XCode 10 with RN version 0.5.7, I tried almost all solutions and nothing worked.

After loosing a lot of time, finally the way I got it to working by doing the following

> 1. Install previous version of react-native by running `react-native init project --version react-native@0.56`
> 2. Open `project/ios/project.xcodeproj` and select `Debug` for command line builds
> 3. Make sure to select the correct development certificate
> 4. Run `react-native run-ios` once again, this time it must work.

Answer (score 0):

Just open the project in xcode app and it will automatically do all the imports and resolve issues. 
Worked for me, Xcode 10+

Edit 1:
Open the iOS folder of your app not your global folder.

Comment: no it doesnt work , with RN 0.57 and Xcode 10.1 , for a brand new react native init app

Comment: It doesn't work for Xcode 11.3 / RN 61.5, either. I can successfully launch in Xcode, but CLI continues to look in the wrong place in the `DerivedData` folder. I have no idea why. The endpoint in this path does not exist `/DerivedData/.../ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React/`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I ran `react-native run-ios --scheme="customscheme"` and the name of customscheme was misspelled.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look into previous error message happened before current error i.e., `"CFBundleIdentifier”, Does Not Exist`.

Fix previous error then this error should disappear.

I fixed previous `duplicate symbols for architecture` error when run `react-native run-ios --simulator="iPad Pro (9.7-inch)`, then the problem gone.

Answer (score 0):

I also get same error while running project
react-native run-ios

But when i run project from xcode, that is work for me.

Comment: did you tried build? and are you continue use without react-native run-ios?

Answer (score 0):

I had a space in my product name. The file system can't find the build directory. I changed "Grace Church" to "GraceChurch". This doesn't affect the display name. Fix in Target > Build Settings > Packaging > Product Name

[image: build settings]

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this steps**

1. Clear Derived Data
2. Build and Run from Xcode
3. Now try with command line

Answer (score -1):

When you run `npm install` command some time internet issue problem, Files in `node_modules\react-native\third-party` is not properly downloaded so please check this is properly downloaded or not if no please remove node_modules and install it again

then run `react-native run-ios`  command

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, none of the mentioned solutions worked for me.

After trying out some of the answers from [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14423), the following finally did work:

As one or more of the required iOS third-party libraries were not properly downloaded to `~/.rncache` (meaning the files in there were corrupted and could not be unzipped), I removed the content of this folder, ran `react-native run-ios` again, and this eventually did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

FIX FOR OSX EL CAPITAN

I'm still on OSX 10.11.6 with XCode 8.2.1 ... will upgrade someday but not today. I was able to get past the :CFBundleIdentifier error by downgrading react native to 52.0

`yarn upgrade react-native@52.0`

Got me a successful build on the simulator. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Adding one to the list of possible causes: *xcodebuild* could be corrupted.

In my case xcodebuild didn't do anything, so it never generated the ios/build/ directory, and the above error resulted.

I used 'which xcodebuild' on the command line, deleted it, and the error was gone

Just took me a while to realize that xcodebuild was bad - I looked at log messages and manually ran the xcodebuild command with the react native parameters - no output of any kind. No build messages, no error messages, nothing. Ran with no params - same....

Leaving this here as one more thing to check if this error message appears. Is your xcodebuild working?

Answer (score -2):

Delete the node modules and run 'npm install' in your project directory.
Now you can able to run the project.

Comment: Just reinstalling node is not a solution