# React-native-fbsdk causes CFBundleIdentifier DNE Error

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

Every time I install & link the react-native-fbsdk in any react-native project, I get this following error from running `react-native run-ios`:

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

The following commands produced analyzer issues:
    Analyze {project-dir}/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.c
    Analyze {project-dir}/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGNodeList.c
(2 commands with analyzer issues)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/{App-Name}.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Failed to install the requested application
The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/{App-Name}/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

I have followed instructions at the [react-native-fbsdk README](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/blob/master/README.md)

and I have followed instructions at the [IOS Getting Started Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/)

Any Project I create works perfectly fine when running `react-native run-ios` before installing & linking the react-native-fbsdk.

Here are the following package versions I am using:

```
npm - 4.6.1
react-native - 0.45.1
react-native-fbsdk - 0.6.0
```

I was originally using  react-native-fbsdk@0.6.1, but it appears that 0.6.1 may have been causing the issue so I changed it to 0.6.0.

I have attempted to create many brand new/fresh 'Hello World' projects and completely install react-native-fbsdk many times, but to no avail and I tried almost ALL of the solutions you can find by googling:
`react-native CFBundleIdentifier doesn't exist`,
`react-native-fbsdk CFBundleIdentifier doesn't exist`,
or some other variation of those 2.

**Edit:** I can run the app on ios via building it in xcode; however, I would like to get rid of the above error in case it might cause any future bugs during release, or with installing any new packages.

Comment: I ran into this issue once and it's been a while, but I remember fixing it by making sure I upgraded React Native to the latest version and XCode to the latest version and turning off and turning back on my computer. Not very satisfying answer I know, but worth a shot. I also remember sometimes having trouble with running the run-ios command from the command line but having more luck when running the build via xcode

Comment: I forgot to mention that it does run by building it via xcode, However, I would like for it to run by using  `react-native run-ios` in case the above error might cause any errors during release. I restarted my computer, made sure I had the latest react & react-native versions by using `react-native-git-upgrade` and yarn adding react-native@latest, but it still will only run through xcode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461703/print-entry-cfbundleidentifier-does-not-exist)