# React Native iOS -- CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Tags: react-native

[image: enter link description here]** BUILD FAILED **

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestApp.app
Hello Team,

I have found issue when running my "TestingApp" in React Native via terminal. I have seen a lot of answer regarding my question but not found any solution which are given by some person.

Error:

An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestApp.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Please provide valid answer if any one has its solution. I am beginner in React Native. Your right ans appreciate me.

Thanks,

Comment: did u solved this ? having same issue.

Comment: Not able to solved. Exactly the scenario is --  when I create new project and run from either Xcode or terminal, its give me above issue.

Comment: my issue got solved. try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40890239/1769274

Comment: Thanks Nabeel for your time. I will update you soon.

Comment: I didn't find any solution on given url. I have tried to change but again get the same issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461703/print-entry-cfbundleidentifier-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 0):

Try to close the Metro Bundler and then write
`npm start -- --reset-cache`

If doesn't work, try to `open the emulator from Xcode` and re-run your react-native project.