# React-Native ios - ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Tags: ios, react-native

I got this error when I run `react-native run-ios`

I tried several solutions I can find online, including

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14969

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12737

and all of them doesn't work for me

Any Clue? I have been stucked for days..

Here is the log:

```
/Users/myName/Documents/work/myApp.com/native_app/ios/myAppNative/AppDelegate.m:31:1: error: missing '@end'
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
^
/Users/myName/Documents/work/myApp.com/native_app/ios/myAppNative/AppDelegate.m:16:1: note: implementation started here
@implementation AppDelegate
^
/Users/myName/Documents/work/myApp.com/native_app/ios/myAppNative/AppDelegate.m:33:1: error: missing context for method declaration
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
^
/Users/myName/Documents/work/myApp.com/native_app/ios/myAppNative/AppDelegate.m:42:1: error: missing context for method declaration
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
^
/Users/myName/Documents/work/myApp.com/native_app/ios/myAppNative/AppDelegate.m:56:1: error: missing context for method declaration
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
^
/Users/myName/Documents/work/myApp.com/native_app/ios/myAppNative/AppDelegate.m:60:1: error: '@end' must appear in an Objective-C context
@end
^
5 errors generated.



** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:

    CompileC build/Build/Intermediates/myAppNative.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myAppNative.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o myAppNative/AppDelegate.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myAppNative.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Failed to install the requested application
The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myAppNative.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461703/print-entry-cfbundleidentifier-does-not-exist)