# Error on running the project in simulator: "Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist"

Tags: react-native, xcode8, react-native-ios

I am setting up React-Native in my laptop. The versions I am using for different tools are as follows:
Node.js : v10.7.0
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.56.0

On running the command "react-native run-ios" I am getting an error like:

```
The following build commands failed:

    CompileC /Users/mshikher/Documents/react-native-workspace/firstProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTShadowView+Internal.o Views/RCTShadowView+Internal.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/firstProject.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/firstProject.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

I have tried a lot of answers in the StackOverflow but nothing has worked till now. What could possibly be the issue behind this.

The recent error I am getting is:

```
The following build commands failed:

        CompileC /Users/mshikher/Documents/react-native-workspace/secondProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTShadowView+Internal.o Views/RCTShadowView+Internal.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    (1 failure)

    Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/secondProject.app
    An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
    Failed to install the requested application
    An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
    Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
    Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

    Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/secondProject.app/Info.plist
    Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461703/print-entry-cfbundleidentifier-does-not-exist)

Comment: This isn't working for me. I am still getting the same error. I upgraded the xocde to 8.2.1 , but still I am facing the same issue.

Comment: did you try react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 7" ?

Comment: Nope this didn't worked for me. I updated the question with the recent error I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

I installed xcode 9.2 which is compatible with macOS 10.12.6. This worked for me.