# when i will run the app in ios i have an error can someone help me?

Tags: react-native, terminal

Failed to install the requested application

The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.

Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.

Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EhackB.app/Info.plist

Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Error: Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EhackB.app/Info.plist

Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Comment: This is not your error you have to see the logs before this one that provoque it.

Comment: Simply searching that error message provides a lot of different steps you could try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461703/print-entry-cfbundleidentifier-does-not-exist

Answer (score 0):

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/AliSonmez/_Git/APP&WEB/EhackB/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/third-party.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/symbolize.o /Users/AliSonmez/_Git/APP&WEB/EhackB/node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.5/src/symbolize.cc normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EhackB.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Failed to install the requested application
The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EhackB.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Error: Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EhackB.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:618:11)
at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:636:13)
at Promise.then (/Users/AliSonmez/_Git/APP&WEB/EhackB/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:208:5)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem seems to be here

```
/Users/AliSonmez/_Git/APP&WEB/EhackB/node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.5/src/symbolize.cc normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (1 failure)
```

with glog-0.3.5 library.