# React-native iOS build is failed

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, bundle-identifier

The react-native iOS build is failed with following error.

```
GB-MAC-01s-MacBook-Pro:rrtest muruganandham.kuppan$ react-native run-ios
Found Xcode project rrtest.xcodeproj
Building using "xcodebuild -project rrtest.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -scheme rrtest -destination id=E7283C81-5F0D-4732-BF8B-19DB3C904DA2 -derivedDataPath build"
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.7.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.7.5
▸ Running script 'Start Packager'
** BUILD FAILED **


Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/rrtest.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Failed to install the requested application
The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

[image]

I have tried few solutions, but no luck.

EDIT: Additional info
[image]

I have changed the react native port to 8088 and modified it in project.

Comment: Usually, the real reason for failure is just above the `** BUILD FAILED **` (the top of your screenshot). Can you try again and see what is shown above that line?

Comment: have you tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461703/print-entry-cfbundleidentifier-does-not-exist

Comment: @MateiRadu pls check now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How I fixed the issue?**

Get the process running in the port 8081

```
sudo lsof -i :8081
```

[image]

and killed it.

```
sudo kill -9 336
```

*336 is the PID (Process ID)

Comment: I just tried this on a 0.53.3 version created from scratch with reproducible error and the above answer did not fix it as it was not an issue of port.