# ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist: ReactNative 0.58 on Mac / iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I am following the ReactNative tutorial for 0.58. I do everything it says to do and I am crashing after running `react-native run-ios`. I have seen this extremely similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461703/print-entry-cfbundleidentifier-does-not-exist) from 2016.

- I attempted `react-native upgrade` and it recommended doing `react-native-git-upgrade.`This did nothing. Same problem.
- The bit on running `./configure` in the question above after cd-ing into `glog` did nothing. There was no `configure` script there. In the path `NewStupidProject/node_modules/react-native/scripts` there is a script called `ios-configure-glog.sh`. I run `bash ios-configure-glog.sh` and it says `ios-configure-glog.sh: line 31: ./configure: No such file or directory`.
- I have also attempted setting Xcode to use the legacy build system. This did not fix the issue. I am restarting my laptop now to see if that makes any of these changes take effect. *No luck.* At the top it says:

> Found Xcode project NewStupidProject.xcodeproj Building using
>   "xcodebuild -project NewStupidProject.xcodeproj -configuration Debug
>   -scheme NewStupidProject -destination id=854019D1-8EE7-4D13-87E1-385E6CAC21BE -derivedDataPath build" User
>   defaults from command line:
>
> ```
> IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/me/NewStupidProject/ios/build
> ```
>
> Prepare build
>
> note: Using legacy build system
>   === BUILD TARGET double-conversion OF PROJECT React WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

When I go into the home directory and run `react-native --version` the output is:

```
[NewStupidProject](master)$ react-native --version
react-native-cli: 2.0.1 
react-native: 0.58.4 
[NewStupidProject](master)$
```

My output after crashing is:

> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
>           PhaseScriptExecution Install\ Third\ Party /Users/me/native_react_apps/NewStupidProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/double-conversion.build/Script-190EE32F1E6A43DE00A8543A.sh
>   (1 failure)
>
> Installing
>   build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NewStupidProject.app An
>   error was encountered processing the command
>   (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22): Failed to install the requested
>   application The bundle identifier of the application could not be
>   determined. Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value
>   for CFBundleIdentifier. Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not
>   Exist
>
> Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier
>   build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NewStupidProject.app/Info.plist
>   Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
>
> Error: Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c
>   Print:CFBundleIdentifier
>   build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NewStupidProject.app/Info.plist
>   Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
>
> ```
> at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:637:11)
> at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:655:13)
> at Promise.then (/Users/me/native_react_apps/NewStupidProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:208:5)
> ```

### How is it possible for the setup process to be this fraught with errors and this difficult?

### WHY is this error message not in the [Troubleshooting ReactNative](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting#content) setup?

### HOW do I fix this? Is it possible to avoid this altogether in the future?

Other versioning info:

- XCode: `10.1`
- Command Line Tools: `10.1`
- yarn: `0.27.5`
- watchman: `4.9.0`
- homebrew: `2.0.1`
- npm: `6.8.0`
- node: `v11.9.0`
- macOS: `10.13.6`

**UPDATE**: 
I am trying to implement the solution in [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20774) in GitHub and I'm getting:

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /usr/local/bin/awk   Reason: image not found
>   ./ios-install-third-party.sh: line 20: 24497 Broken pipe: 13
>   shasum -p "$cachedir/$file"
>        24498 Abort trap: 6           | awk -v hash="$hash" '{exit $1 != hash}' Incorrect hash: 61067502c5f9769d111ea1ee3f74e6ddf0a5f9cc
>   ?/Users/me/.rncache/glog-0.3.5.tar.gz

**UPDATE No. 2** I am trying to run the `watchman watch-del-all` command as recommended [here](https://gist.github.com/jarretmoses/c2e4786fd342b3444f3bc6beff32098d) to clear the cache for RN > 0.50 and the whole thing is hanging.

[image]

Comment: Yeah so I set the project settings to use the legacy build settings, restarted my computer, and ran `react-native run-ios` and it is still throwing up all over my console. Something about `glog` and the `bundle.` This is beyond frustrating. Ironically, I am trying to convince my friend how great `react-native init` is over using Expo and `expo init`. Not going well.

Comment: That is annoying. Have you cleaned the build folder? This issue should no longer exist on  on version `0.58.+` and I haven't experienced it since upgrading.  You should also look at this for properly clearing the [cache](https://gist.github.com/jarretmoses/c2e4786fd342b3444f3bc6beff32098d). I have also used this [script](https://gist.github.com/fiznool/739b8e592596b5731512edfd77a1a2e9) to fix the 3rd party issue

Comment: Thank you for this. I will run that script afterwards, looks good. Is `watchman watch-del-all` expected to take a long time? It seems to be hanging.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help, Andrew. I'll try this and report back. Do you have any insight to long-term solutions for this?

Comment: No idea, I don't have this problem with version `0.58.+`. Most issues I encounter  are resolved by either removing the build folder, clearing the cache, or by building from Xcode, or a combination.

Comment: Thanks again. This `watchman watch-del-all` is literally taking hours. Can I inspect the output of this anywhere to verify it is doing something?

Comment: It shouldn’t take hours. You need to kill it as it sounds like it has hung/crashed

Comment: @ScottSkiles, did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Sadly, no. The breaking changes between React Native upgrades and XCode / macOS are really doing my head in and have given up for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I tried modify the build system and it worked for me.

Detail:

Open your project workspace file in Xcode, and

```
File -> Workspace Settings -> Build system -> Legacy Build system
```