# Why am I unable to use glog due to incorrect hash?

Tags: react-native, glog

Related to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54717896/cfbundleidentifier-does-not-exist-reactnative-0-58-on-mac-ios) on ReactNative init setup process being awful, I am unable to download glog due to an incorrect hash. Does anyone know what is going on here? How can I fix this so that I can use react-native properly? I have tried clearing my entire `.rncache` and it did nothing.

It does look like [glog-0.3.5](https://github.com/google/glog/releases) is the most recent version... so why am I having a nightmare of a time using this? Why is the hash incorrect? Does ReactNative install something with a different hash than it is supposed to?

> Incorrect hash:
>
> 61067502c5f9769d111ea1ee3f74e6ddf0a5f9cc
>   ?/Users/me/.rncache/glog-0.3.5.tar.gz
>
> Retrying...
>
> Failed to successfully download 'glog-0.3.5.tar.gz'.  Debug info:
>
> -rw-r--r--  1 root  staff  532275 Feb 15 18:24 /Users/me/.rncache/glog-0.3.5.tar.gz
>
> 61067502c5f9769d111ea1ee3f74e6ddf0a5f9cc 
>   /Users/me/.rncache/glog-0.3.5.tar.gz
>
> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Answer (score 1):

My error was located a bit above yours in the console.

```
Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib
```

I fixed this by symlinking to the version I had.

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
```

If the lib does not exists and you are using Mac you can use a custom brash with brew.
https://itnext.io/upgrading-bash-on-macos-7138bd1066ba

Answer (score 1):

Actually @FOLOG's suggestion, while working, was a bit of a ghetto fix. I encountered this issue and went to dig a little further and found the culprit to be gawk.

The clue is here: `Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/awk`

Assuming you are on Mac, just run `brew upgrade gawk` to fix the problem.