# Upgraded React Native and now getting glog/logging.h file not found

Tags: xcode, reactjs, react-native, glog

I've upgraded React Native from 0.52 to 0.59 I'm aware this is a massive jump but I thought might as well go for it, and now getting `glog/logging.h file not found.`

I'm also aware that there are similar questions on here. But I've literally tried everything out there and I just can't seem to get this issue fixed.

Here's one of the things that I've tried:

`cd node_modules/react-native/scripts && ./ios-install-third-party.sh && cd ../../../`

`cd node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4/ && ../../scripts/ios-configure-glog.sh && cd ../../../../`

Anyone would think this would solve it right? I've left no stone unterned and it just doesn't want to go away. Fun!

[image]

Comment: I have a similar question on this... I think a ticket needs to be opened with the RN repo directly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54725742/why-am-i-unable-to-use-glog-due-to-incorrect-hash

Answer (score 1):

Found a reference to the XCode app name having spaces here:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19774

I also found that as I was using multiple versions, I had "XCode 10.1.app". When I changed it to XCode.app (and run something like `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app` to update the XCode path), my app built without this problem or any of the others I'd experienced to date with glog.

Comment: Thanks this saved me from a lot of trouble. I was using Xcode 11.2.1 (with a space) for an old react native app and this was the only way to move past the issue.