# Usage of ios/index/DataStore

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I've recently upgraded my RN version using [rn-diff-purge](https://github.com/pvinis/rn-diff-purge), and immediately I'm hitting error. And eventually fixed it using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41854111/9816472).

Now it works best in both Debug and Release for both iOS and Android. However, I noticed there is a new massive folder being created under `ios`. Specifically `ios/Index`.

Now I'm wondering if this is belongs to Xcode and can be safely add to `.gitignore`?

Comment: @Issac Did you get any solution for this

Comment: Did you added all the files to .gitignore