# "CFBundleIdentifier Does Not Exist" when building Staging scheme in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to get a react-native iOS setup working that includes a Staging scheme/configuration.

So far I managed to get all three schemes working inside of Xcode and I am able to install them alongside each other in one simulator as well.

However, for some reason, when I try to run

`react-native run-ios --scheme "staging" --configuration "Staging"`

in the CLI, the build succeeds but I get the error:

`Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist`

Now, I noticed that in the build folder, I always end up with a partial Staging product and a partial Release product when building the Staging scheme.

Below, you will find screenshots of my build folder after running the build command for with Staging configuration/scheme.

As you can see, the app itself (including the Info.plist) is located not under `Staging-iphonesimulator` but `Release-iphonesimulator`.

I am not sure if this desired behaviour or not, or if I just need to point the Staging scheme to the correct folder in my Search paths?

Any help would be enormously appreciated!

I already tried:

- Cleaning cache/build folders
- Updating dependencies

[image]

[image]

Comment: This thread helped me when I came across this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461703/print-entry-cfbundleidentifier-does-not-exist

Comment: @Perniferous Thanks for the advice. I tried the top solution but it sadly doesn't seem to do anything. Can you tell me what you did?

Comment: For me the error seemed somewhat random as I tried tons of the solutions on that question to no avail, after running "npm install" seemingly a million times, doing the configure glog solution, cleaning xcode, linked my modules, and restarted my computer and it started working. Definitely no concrete fix as my app just suddenly started working. Unfortunately this error is super common and its a tough one to diagnose in my experience.

Comment: @ReinVanImschoot just try `react-native link` command inside your project folder