# Fresh React Native project failing: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Tags: ios, react-native, cfbundleidentifier

I'm trying to set up a fresh React Native project by simply following the guide here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

I can build and run it from Xcode just fine, only getting a few "semantic warnings".

When I run `yarn react-native run-ios` though, I get the following error:

```
Leos-MacBook-Pro:citymysteryrn leo$ yarn react-native run-ios
yarn run v1.19.1
$ /Users/leo/Projekt/ReactNative/CityMysteryRN/node_modules/.bin/react-native run-ios
info Found Xcode workspace "CityMysteryRN.xcworkspace"
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace CityMysteryRN.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme CityMysteryRN -destination id=85422E57-5311-43D4-9292-E02982FB7B67 -derivedDataPath build/CityMysteryRN")
..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
info Installing "DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CityMysteryRN.app"
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
error Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CityMysteryRN.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CityMysteryRN.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:639:15)
    at runOnSimulator (/Users/leo/Projekt/ReactNative/CityMysteryRN/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/index.js:189:45)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/leo/Projekt/ReactNative/CityMysteryRN/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/cliEntry.js:160:7)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I know there are tons of questions (and answers) related to this, but it seems to be a very broad issue that I can't solve. I've tried most things on [Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461703/print-entry-cfbundleidentifier-does-not-exist) without any luck.

I've also tried comparing this project to older React Native projects that I know are running and have identified the following differences, but don't know if they are of any importance:

- Missing folder `third-party` in `node_modules/react-native/`
- Build folder contains folder `ios/build/MyProjectName` containing `Logs`, `info.plist` etc, while older projects have these files and folders directly in `ios/build/`

Here's the output of `yarn react-native info`

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.1
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7360U CPU @ 2.30GHz
    Memory: 296.96 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.13.1 - /var/folders/5k/d42fx4ms6pv83hp9q0f9xvh40000gn/T/yarn--1574448680125-0.03761777189202431/node
    Yarn: 1.19.1 - /var/folders/5k/d42fx4ms6pv83hp9q0f9xvh40000gn/T/yarn--1574448680125-0.03761777189202431/yarn
    npm: 6.12.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
  IDEs:
    Xcode: 11.2.1/11B500 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: ^2.9.0 => 2.10.0 
    react: 16.8.6 => 16.8.6 
    react-native: 0.60.5 => 0.60.5 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7
    react-native: 0.53.3
```

CFBundleIdentifier in `/ios/MyProjectName/Info.plist` looks like this:

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
```

Comment: Do you have `CFBundleIdentifier` inside your Info.plist file ? Could you try to delete your ìos/build` folder and run command again ?

Comment: Yes, it is there. Added the value in the question above. Deleting the `build` folder and running `yarn react-native run-ios` again results in the build folder being created and then the same error. Building and running from Xcode still works fine though.

Comment: And the bundle id value is not empty ? I will looking for another solution

Comment: Nope, the bundle identifier field in the Xcode project has a value.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a proper solution, but.

I got fed up, backed up my MacBook and wiped the whole thing clean. It now works.